# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" When trying to sort an array

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new to programming and trying to program a sensor. I'm sorting the array that I plot the input from the sensor into. But I'm running into a problem when sorting it, it gives me this error:

> exit status 1
>   void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Here's my code:

```
#include <ArduinoSort.h>

int a[10];
int b[10];
int sensor1 = A0;
int sensor2 = A1;
int display1;
int display2;
int sort[10];

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    delay(100);
    Serial.print("Sensor 1: [");

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        display1 = analogRead(sensor1);
        a[i] = display1;
        sort[i] = sortArray(a, 10);
        if (i < 10) {
            Serial.print(String(sort[i]) + ",");
        } else {
            Serial.print(String(sort[i]));
        }
    }

    Serial.print("]");
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print("Sensor 2: [");
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        display2 = analogRead(sensor2);
        b[i] = display2;
        if (i < 10) {
            Serial.print(String(b[i]) + ",");
        } else {
            Serial.print(String(b[i]));
        }

    }
    Serial.print("]");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    //String hej = "Sensor 1"+ String(display1);
    //Serial.println(hej);
}
```

and, on this line I get the error:

```
sort[i] = sortArray(a,10);
```

Comment: What does `sortArray` return? Probably `void`.

Comment: I dont know, how can i found out?

And its only a problem when i add sort[i] before the equal sign, othewise it doesn't give me an error

Comment: Mark, where did you get `ArduinoSort.h` from?

Comment: @JohnFilleau https://github.com/emilv/ArduinoSort from here

Comment: The documentation and code are right there. That's where you can find out.

Comment: Thank you, just had a quick read through and can see where i might have misunderstood it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sortArray()](https://github.com/emilv/ArduinoSort/blob/bb1d4d3adc6d5044749923009d23eaa29ad9ecdb/ArduinoSort.h#L7) function returns nothing i.e. `void`.

It sorts the passed array in-place so you need to call it like this:

```
sortArray(a, 10); // no return value assignment
```

---

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017405/void-value-not-ignored-as-it-ought-to-be-when-trying-to-sort-an-array/61017496?noredirect=1#comment107949748_61017496) by [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt), you have not initialized `a` properly so you need to first collect all the values and then sort it after the loop.

Here's your loop (after correction of `sortArray` after loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {  // 0-10 i.e. 11 iterations
    a[i] = analogRead(sensor1); // read values in the array
    // ...
}

sortArray(a, 10); // sort after the loop
```

---

Another problem is that your loop's condition is `i < 11` which means the iterations from 0 to 10 i.e. 11 iterations. But, the arrays you're using are of size 10 i.e. 0 to 9 locations as C++ arrays are ZERO-based. So, this is causing out-of-bounds access resulting in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

So, your loop iterations and the array sizes should match i.e. 10 iterations and 10 memory locations to write to.

It's better to use a constant and use that at all places like this:

```
const int SIZE = 10;

int a[SIZE] = {0}; // initialize if it's not an overhead for arduino

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    a[i] = analogRead(sensor1);
    // ...
}

sortArray(a, SIZE);
```

Comment: Of course the 10 is also wrong because it will sort the portion not yet filled in.  I'm not sure what exactly OP hopes to accomplish by throwing a sort call into the middle of a loop.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is trying to read a sequence of values then sort them. Of course this means the sorting should be done after the reading but the OP has got confused and tried to sort as they go along.

Comment: Yeah, sorry thats because when i started this as you see i just print the array as it comes in, and for it to print the array the way i wanted i did it that way, and just thought i might be able to sort the array and then print it like had already done

Comment: So with this im still able to do it in the void loop()? but just not in the "for" loop?

Comment: @MarkDrongesen: `void loop()`? I believe you meant `while loop`. Yes, you can use `while` loop but it's better to use `for` loop in this scenario. Just take care of the iterations as C++ arrays are ZERO-based.

Answer (score 0):

You have a somewhat bigger problem with this code.

You simply cannot "print outputs in sorted order" while you are still collecting them.  You don't know whether the "smallest" **right now** should be printed, or wait because an even smaller one is forthcoming.